# Is "likes nothing less" or "likes nothing more" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

> 1. He likes nothing less than an extremely sophisticated life.
> 2. He likes nothing more than an extremely sophisticated life.

Both look meaningfully similar. In the first one, 'less' appears to act on the object while in the second line, the word 'more' appears to act on on the verb. Which one is correct in terms of grammatical accuracy?

Comment: I have heard both usages commonly and generally in some movies

Comment: Both meaningful and grammatical, but they mean different things. Think over. If still in doubt, ask on [ell.se]

Comment: Is it like this?

The first one says, anything of a lower quality than extreme sophistication is disliked by him.

and

The second one says, Anything other than sophisticated life is lesser liked by him.

Comment: I meant, 

The first one says, "he likes anything of a lower quality than extreme sophistication lesser" and the second one says, "he likes anything other than extreme sophistication lesser".

Comment: Isn't that so? Each has its uses in the right context, right?

Comment: So that is it. Thanks! But my part where I said 'less' acts on the object while 'more' acts on on the verb should be correct, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some subtle differences, but both phrases are used to imply the same overall concept: In simplest terms:

> He likes an extremely sophisticated life.

Readers can reach this conclusion regardless of which phrase you choose. Whoever "he" is, a sophisticated life is the life for him. There are, however, different connotations regarding each phrase. For example, take a look at the first phrase:

---

> **1.** He likes **nothing less** than an extremely sophisticated life.

This sentence implies that Man #1 will be unhappy if his life is *anything* short of "extremely sophisticated". Force him to live a more humble lifestyle, and he certainly won't enjoy it. The use of "extremely" also implies that this man wants to live *as sophisticated as possible* - a golden cheese fork would be inadequate when Man #1 knows he can buy a platinum one!

---

> **2.** He likes **nothing more** than an extremely sophisticated life.

Man #2 is content to reach "extremely sophisticated" status and *go no farther*. If bathing in emeralds is deemed sophisticated enough, this man would see no reason to upgrade to diamond-encrusted bathwater. The phrase comes off as less of an obsession for "ultimate fanciness," but more of an achievable dream to be just the right amount of "fancy."

Comment: That was very well explained.